# Can't create custom audience from instagram audience

Tags: instagram, ads, meta-business-suite

In **Meta Business Suite**, I want to create a custom audience from people who interacted with content from my professional Instagram account, as described in this [article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xx54L.png) of the Meta Business Help Center.

What I tried:
I added my Instagram account under "business settings/Instagram accounts". I also added my Facebook profile under "people who have access to" my Instagram account (don't know if this is necessary).  Then I go to "audiences" in the burger menu and click on "create custom audience". Here I choose my Instagram account under "Meta sources".

Here the problem occurs: my Instagram account is not shown in the list.
My Instagram Account is definitely a professional account.
What's wrong?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to go into Business Settings in your Business Manager > Accounts > Instagram accounts > Connected assets > Add assets, then select your ad account. Worked for me, hope it does for you.